# Restore multiple tables postgresql pg_dump

Tags: postgresql

I have a database with several tables and I want to add the data and structure of a selection of them to a different database containing already different tables.

I have created the dump file in the following way:

```
"C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.1\bin\pg_dump.exe" -U postgres -w DBName -t table1 -t Table2 -t Table3 > "E:\Dump.sql"
```

This works fine and I have E:\Dump.sql with the dump of the three tables in it.
I have tried to make a restore with the following code:

```
"C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.6\bin\pg_dump.exe" -C -U User -t table1 -t Table2 -t Table4 destdb < Dump.sql
```

but I get the error

> no matching tables were found

.

Where am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/backup-dump.html

`pg_dump` is meant for **taking* backups, next section  of manual is for restoring a backup:

> Text files created by pg_dump are intended to be read in by the psql
>   program. The general command form to restore a dump is
>
> `psql dbname < infile`

Also you mention three tables, two of which are mixed case - in order for it to work, you have to double quote it I believe. But anyway - restoring for you file would be:

```
psql YOURDBNAME -f E:\Dump.sql
```